# Android Broadcast Receiver after app install

Tags: android, installation, broadcast

I developed an app that receives the boot completed intent. From my tests I concluded that I must open the app at least once to start receiveing this intent.

Is this the correct behavior? If so, is there any way to start receiveing intents without starting my app at least once?

Thanks,

-George

Answer (score 0):

The app must be opened before any code can be triggered, there is no way around this.